# Predicting a Value using Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

[image]

I got this question wrong on an exam, and I'm still struggling to see where the right inputs come from.

I'm fairly sure the equation necessary to solve it is

$$\hat{Y} = b_0 + b_1X_i$$

$$\text{where}$$

$$X_i = 85.650
$$

$$\text{It doesn't seem possible to solve for }b_1\text{ or }b_0  \text{ with the provided information so I thought this was probably provided as coefficient.}$$
However, I can't seem to arrive at an answer choice that's actually provided.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing? What does "Coefficients" mean in the heading of the exhibit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we use the convention of$$\hat{Y}_i = b_0 \color{blue}{+}b_1 X_i$$

where $b_0$ is the intercept and $b_1$ is the coefficient of odometer.

Comment: Yes! What I meant to write, sorry. Edited. Learning Latex as I go

Comment: what is the correct answer?

Comment: It's 5.95, which I can arrive at now with your help. But I have a bit of trouble understanding what it means when the inputs are written like this. I don't know what exactly it means to be a "Coefficient" or an "Intercept".

Comment: I see, that is actually the layout of software output like R.